# Coroutines working on Android emulator but not in real device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-architecture-components

I have been dealing with a problem trying to synchronize the remote and local datasources operations with coroutines that only happens when I run the app in a real device, in the AS emulator everything works fine. I have tried to follow all the guides, codelabs and samples Google propose to follow the same structures and architectures and the result is always the same: working on the emulator, failing on the real device. I have tried with two different real devices with different OS versions and both of them fail.

What I'm trying to achieve is just perform a request to an API (through retrofit) and save the result in the DB. When executing from real device and using the debugger, it seems that at some point something is executed and the app crashes or do nothing. My code:

**RetrofitService:**

```kotlin
@GET("product/{id}")
    suspend fun getFoodByBarCode(@Path("id") id: String): FoodSchema
```

**RemoteDataSource**: None of this exceptions are thrown at any moment

```kotlin
class FoodRemoteDataSource(private val foodService: FoodService) {

    suspend fun getFoodByBarCode(code: String): Result<Food> = performRequest(RemoteMapper()) { foodService.getFoodByBarCode(code) }

    private suspend fun <T, R> performRequest(modelMapper: BaseMapper<T, R>, call: suspend () -> T): Result<R> {
        try {
            val response = call()
            if(response != null) return Result.Success(modelMapper.execute(response)) else throw Exception("The server response is null")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

**Database DAO**

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM food")
    fun observeAllFood(): LiveData<List<Food>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertFood(food: Food)
```

**LocalDataSource**

```kotlin
class FoodLocalDataSource(
    private val foodDao: FoodDao,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) : FoodDataSource {

    override fun observeAllFood(): LiveData<Result<List<Food>>> {
        return foodDao.observeAllFood().map { Success(it) }
    }

    override suspend fun saveFood(food: Food) =
        withContext(ioDispatcher) { foodDao.insertFood(food) }
```

**Repository**

```kotlin
class FoodRepository(private val localDataSource: FoodLocalDataSource,
                     private val remoteDataSource: FoodRemoteDataSource) : FoodDataSource {

    override fun observeAllFood(): LiveData<Result<List<Food>>> {
        return localDataSource.observeAllFood()
    }

    suspend fun fetchFoodByBarCode(barCode: String) {
        val result = remoteDataSource.getFoodByBarCode(barCode)
        if(result.succeeded) saveFood((result as Result.Success).data)
    }

    override suspend fun saveFood(food: Food) {
        localDataSource.saveFood(food)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```kotlin
class FoodListViewModel(private val foodRepository: FoodRepository) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _foodList = requestFoodList()
    val foodList: LiveData<List<Food>> = _foodList

    private fun requestFoodList(): LiveData<List<Food>> {
        showLoading()
        return foodRepository.observeAllFood().distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap { extractResult(it) }
    }

    fun fetchFoodByBarCode(barCode: String) {
        launchDataLoad { foodRepository.fetchFoodByBarCode(barCode) }
    }
    
    private fun <T : Any> extractResult(
        result: Result<T>,
        autoHideLoading: Boolean = true
    ): LiveData<T> {
        val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<T>().apply { value = null }
        if (autoHideLoading) hideLoading()
        when (result) {
            is Result.Success -> {
                mutableLiveData.value = result.data!!
            }
            is Result.Error -> {
                _error.value = true
                mutableLiveData.value = null
            }
        }
        return mutableLiveData
    }
}
```

My activity just observe the `foodList` to populate a RecyclerView and calls the `fetchFoodByBarCode()` when a button is clicked.

Any idea what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the [logs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat), you probably have updated a database field or something and not specified to update the version on room or deleted the app on the device before installing it so that the room schema is updated.

Comment: @peprumo I've been checking the logcat and there are not meaningful messages. I also try to remove the APP on my device and increase the DB version (destructive migration) so everything is brand new. Still not working